# XMind Excute Error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

i installed XMind 7.5 on Ubuntu18.04.
(sudo dpkg -i xmind-kr-7.5-linux_amd64.deb)
but, when i excuted the XMind, it can not do.

i don't know why it isn't excuted.
would you guys help me?

> XMind
>   WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>   WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller (file:/usr/lib/xmind/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.101.v20150820-1432.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
>   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller
>   WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
>   Gtk-Message: 14:18:15.092: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
>
> java --version
>   openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)

Comment: Guess you should've posted that on https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

It looks like need to explicitly define the path to JRE that requires XMind (in my case for *XMind8* should be used *java 8*).

Edit **XMind.ini** and add these lines to the top:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
# ..
```

See for details [Force XMind to use Java 7](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/force-xmind-to-use-java-7/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for on Ubuntu 18.04